# How to Shuffle the UITableview rows dynamically

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

Hi I am working with the `Tableview`.I am having an array consists of Date object. Based on Date and time how i can shuffle the tableview rows.This array get the values dynamically so how to achieve this.

And about my code: I am just retuning my array count and assigning name in tableview titleLabel.It is working fine. But i need to shuffle based on date.

Comment: shuffle or sort by date and time?

Comment: i mean i want to change the rows based on  and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -moveRowAtIndexPath delegate method of UITableView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{
if (fromIndexPath != toIndexPath ) {
  //Your desired moving login here
}
}
```

And set:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have Array - dataSource for table.
2. Just to make shuffle for this array's items.

   ```
   // Shuffle part
   int count = [myMutableArray count];

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       int newRange = count - i;
       int newI = (arc4random() % newRange) + i;
       [myMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:newI];
   }
   ```
3. Reload your tableView.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.But How to shuffle array.

Comment: Ok But where i need to assign my date value please help me

Comment: Use TableViewDataSource protocol methods for assign your data to cells: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: No I mean in your code where i have to compare the date

Comment: I have suggested that you have an array with some NSDate objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110262/discussion-between-gerram-and-bittoo).